# How do I document the return type which comes from another method?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

When a method is returning the result of a call to another method, what is the sensible way to document the return type?

```
class A
{
    /**
     * @return [How do I know here what bar will return?]
     */
    public function foo()
    {
        $b = new B();
        return $b->bar();
    }
}

class B
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function bar()
    {
        return 'baz';
    }
}
```

How do I document `A::foo()` return type, when it is not certain what `B::baz()` will return? In the future, `B::baz()` may change, in which case the return type of `A::foo()` unknowingly changes.

Is this a code smell? Can the wider code be designed so that the return type of `A::foo()` is predictable even if `B::baz()` changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fear that the `bar()` return type could change without regard to what your `foo()` expects, then I'd say it is indeed a code smell.  There's apparently no contract between the two, so there's no trust from `A` to `B`.

More practically, `bar()` is *documented* to return `string`, so by having `foo()` coded to return `bar()`'s actual return, then `foo()` should be documented to also return `string`.  There won't be an *automatic* way for the doc generator / IDE to keep up with this *for you*, if that's what you're after.

The other doc-only option would be to mark `foo()`'s return as `mixed`, thereby telling the reader "I make no guarantees on what I return, because I'm only giving you what `bar()` gave me, and I don't know ahead of time what that will be".

Answer (score 0):

If we're speaking on higher type-strict and you should refactor your code and tell to bar() what kind of type will be returned : (PHP >7.0)

```
class A
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function foo()
    {
        $b = new B();
        return $b->bar();
    }
}

class B
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function bar() : string
    {
        return 'baz';
    }
}
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

But in your case I'll put `B\bar` as return type, because you're returning instance of class `B` and method `bar`.

```
         * @return B\bar
         */
        public function foo()
        {
```